# MYSQL date values in rows to dynamic columns

Tags: mysql

**I cant seem to get around this issue. I'm new to MYSQL and been trying some stuff out.
Spare some time to help??**

```
SELECT stu.stud_id Student_ID, stu.lastname Student_Name, sec.sect_id, a.attend_status Attendance_Status, date(a.datetime) Attendance_Date 
FROM student stu 
INNER JOIN attendance a ON (stu.stud_id=a.stud_id) 
INNER JOIN section sec ON (a.sect_id=sec.sect_id) 
GROUP BY a.datetime
```

[output of the query above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JjPQ.png)

expected output:

```
   +----+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+ 
   | id |    name   | 2018-02-07| 2018-02-08| new date  |
   |    |           |           |           | if added  |
   +----+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+ 
   |  1 |    Alupig |   present |      null |    ----   |
   |  3 |     Perez |   present |      null |    ----   | 
   |  2 |    Verana |      null |   present |    ----   | 
   +----+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9668036/851432)

Comment: @Jomoos I don't think it answer the problem, it's for fixed columns.

Comment: Unfortunately MySQL does not have a `PIVOT` function which is basically what you are trying to do. So you will have to resort to `CASE` statement. :/

Comment: if we add php and javascript in the picture, would pivoting then be possible?

Comment: FYI-This is not an answer but will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241178/mysql-rows-to-columns

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code